# bash Storing program parameters in variable wont work when calling program

Tags: bash, variables, parameters

I want to write a function in my bash_profile to log some parameters I use to execute a program. Problem is, when I store the parameters in a variable, i get errors when I call my program.

```
#!/bin/bash

para="-db ~/Desktop/search_for_TDS/claClusterSeq -query ~/path/to/file/abc -out ~/Desktop/hallo_blast123"

/home/xyz/blastn $para
```

This produces an error:

```
Command line argument error: Argument "query". File is not accessible:  `~/path/to/file/abc'
```

While this wont:

```
#!/bin/bash

/home/xyz/blastn -db ~/Desktop/search_for_TDS/claClusterSeq -query ~/path/to/file/abc -out ~/Desktop/hallo_blast123
```

both times executed by calling `bash test.sh` on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS for testing.

Here is the actual function I want in my bash_profile if this is of interest:

```
blastv25table(){

    if [[ ! $# = 5 ]];   then

        echo "Param: query db wordSize task evalue"

    else

        #== Parameters ==

        DATE=$(date -I)

        para="-num_threads 8
         -query $1
         -db $2
         -outfmt 6
         -task $4
         -word_size $3
         -out $PWD/"$1"_"$4"_ws_"$3"_eval_"$5"_Result_"$DATE"_table
         -evalue $5
         "

        #== Parameter logfile ==

        log="./blast_param.log"

        echo -e 'Timestamp\t: '$(date)'\nQuery file\t: '$1'\nDB file\t\t: '$2'\nParameters\t: '$para'\nBlastn\t\t: v2.5\n\n##---------------------------##\n' >> $log


        #======= Start Blastn ======

        /home/xyz/blastn $para

    fi
}
```

The error that first lead to my testing was caused by:

`-out $PWD/"$1"_"$4"_ws_"$3"_eval_"$5"_Result_"$DATE"_table`

where I wanted to use the directory from where the script was called to be used in the output parameter of blastn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your short example, the tilde does *not* expand in a quoted string.

You want to use an array variable instead of pushing all your options into a single string:

```
blastv25table() {
    if [[ $# -ne 5 ]];   then
        echo "Param: query db wordSize task evalue"
    else
        date=$(date -I)
        para=(
         -num_threads 8
         -query "$1"
         -db "$2"
         -outfmt 6
         -task "$4"
         -word_size "$3"
         -out "$PWD/${1}_${4}_ws_${3}_eval_${5}_Result_${date}_table"
         -evalue "$5"
        )
        log="./blast_param.log"

        printf 'Timestamp\t: %s\nQuery file\t: %s\nDB file\t\t: %s\nParameters\t: %s\nBlastn\t\t: v2.5\n\n##---------------------------##\n' \
          "$(date)" "$1" "$2" "${para[*]}" >> $log

        /home/xyz/blastn "${para[@]}"
    fi
}
```

If you want the output file to be in the same directory as the `blastn` program, do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
blast_dir=$(dirname "$0")
...
blastv25table() {
    ...
         -out "$blast_dir/${1}_${4}_ws_${3}_eval_${5}_Result_${date}_table"
```

Comment: Thanks, this and a fix for a little error with the `-out` line did it. `"$PWD/$(basename ${1})_${4}_ws_${3}_eval_${5}_Result_${date}_table"` the basename command to strip the path if I supply a file somewhere distant